# Валидация поля email в view

Tags: yii2, yii, валидация

В процессе создания сайта у меня появилась необходимость валидировать поле email на фронте т.е сделать что-то по типу emailvalidator, только чтоб выглядело это как regex т.е пользователь не мог ввести лишние символы в поле. Какие есть варианты осуществления этого? Вариант с созданием своего валидатора не пройдет только потому что если появится необходимость добавить новый символ в поле( не на всех страницах ) то будет дублирование.

Comment: Чем стандартный input type email не устроил?

Comment: @Streletz Тем что мне не нужно сообщение об ошибке под полем, мне нужно чтоб нельзя было вообще вводить символы не относящиеся к почте.

Comment: Ну повесьте на change обработчик через JS и там проверяйте, что вводите.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно поняла, то попробуйте InputMask, это встроенный виджет, который как раз таки и позволяет вписывать только нужные символы для телефона или email.

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\widgets\MaskedInput;
?>

  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'create_application',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
]); ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), ['mask' => '+7(999)-999-99-99',])->textInput(['placeholder' => '+7(999)-999-99-99']); ?>


      <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), ['name' => 'input-36','clientOptions' => ['alias' =>  'email'],]); ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'button_form']) ?>
    </div>

  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению не могу пока что проверить сработает ли так как мне нужно, в ближ дни проверю и если всё нормально - укажу ответ верным.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте валидатор [match](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#match)

P.S. Только все равно не понятно как у вас на одной странице могут быть разные разрешенные символы для email, если это всегда текст-цифры, точки, и символ `@`.

Comment: Я совершенно с вами согласен, но дело в том что это не для себя я делаю, мне сказали что нужно именно так. + match используется для валидации на backend стороне а меня интересует ( как я уже несколько раз описывал выше ) именно frontend т.е поле в ActiveForm. Но в любом случае - спасибо что уделили моему вопросу время.

Comment: match будет использоваться и на фронте если вы используете ActiveForm